# testing default cases of function params using jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

on the below snippet code , how can i check the object default case in actualData function.

when i run the jest coverage i am getting branch as not 100 percentage becuase i didnt written a test case for object default case.

how can i check that one

Please see the below snippet code. Any help appreciated :)

// sample.js

```
    let data = {
  users: [
    {
      terms: ["service|/users"],
      conditions: ["view", 'create']
    },
    {
      terms: ["service|/users-details"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["service|/usersNew"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["list|searchuser"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["list|createuser"],
      conditions: ["view", "create"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["service|/user-contacts"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["service|/user-location"],
      conditions: ["view"]
    },
    {
      terms: ["page|supplierlist|button|select"],
      conditions: ["enable"]
    },
    {
      terms:["page|supplierlist|button|create-new"],
      conditions: ["disable"]
    }
  ]
};


class Mapper{
  constructor(data){
    this.currentIndex = -1;
    this.data = this.extractData(data);
  }

  resolveData(terms, object={}, conditions){
    try{
      return terms.reduce((result, string) => {
        const [key, value] = string.split(/\|(.+)/);
        if (value && value.includes('|')) {
          result[key] = result[key] || {};
          this.resolveData([value], result[key], conditions);
        } else {
          result[key] = result[key] || [];
          this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex + 1;
          result[key].push({ [value]: conditions[this.currentIndex] });
        }
        return result;
      }, object);
    }catch(error){
      throw error
    }
  }


  extractData(data){
    try{
      let terms = data.users.map(o => o.terms)
      terms = [].concat(...terms);
      const conditions = data.users.map(o => o.conditions);
      return this.resolveData(terms, {}, conditions)
    }catch(error){
      throw error
    }
  }
}
```

// sample.test.js

```
 const Mapper = require('./Sample');


describe('Sample File test cases', () => {
    test('should throw an error', () => {
        const resolvedSample = {}
        expect(() => {
          const model = new Mapper(resolvedSample)
        }).toThrow(TypeError);
    })
})
```

Comment: What is `actualData` supposed to do?  It's hard to help with a test for code that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you code coverage for that line:

```
test('resolveData should handle error', () => {
  const model = new Mapper({ users: [] });
  expect(() => { model.resolveData(); }).toThrow();
})
```

...having said that, you should probably just remove the default argument since `resolveData` is always called with all three arguments.

You can also remove the `try/catch` from both functions since the `catch` doesn't do anything besides throw the error.

Comment: so we shouldn't use try catch , i have read some where what ever you write it should be in a try catch . Is there any memory issue or something

Comment: it worked for me can you explain how it worked , like when we make toThrow it should go to the catch block or am i little confused on this

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS If code is wrapped in a `try/catch` and the `catch` simply throws the error that it just caught then the code will behave exactly the same if the `try/catch` is removed.  So removing the `try/catch` cuts down on the amount of code and slightly improves performance.  (If the `catch` does something besides just immediately throwing the error that it just caught then it might be useful and worth keeping)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS The test in the answer calls `resolveData` with no arguments so the default argument for `object` is used which covers that line in the code coverage report for `Jest`.  Calling `resolveData` with no arguments causes an error to be thrown so I wrapped the call in an `expect(...).toThrow();`

Comment: great. I am new to unit testing . I have some doubts on this one can you please check and help to write in a proper way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257606/writing-test-for-service-calls-in-enzyme-react

Comment: is it possible can you share your email , If you could help it will be a great help :)

Comment: any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257606/writing-test-for-service-calls-in-enzyme-react